# Translating the idea of the verb "to mean"

Tags: grammar, words

Let's say I'm explaning the meaning of a word in my mother tongue to a Japanese.

> 'Pomme' means apple in French.

I have three possibilities of translating this.

> ポムとは、フランス語でりんごっていう意味だ。
>
> ポムとは、フランス語でりんごっていう意味がある。
>
> ポムとは、フランス語でりんごっていう意味がする。

Are those sentence all correct, and what are the differences between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first sentence is correct and natural.

> ポムとは、フランス語でりんご｛っていう/という｝意味だ。

"Pomme means apple in French."

Of course you can also say:

> ポム**は**、フランス語でりんご｛っていう/という｝意味だ。

<sub>(Basically, if you use ～～**と**は, you'd end the sentence with 「[noun]+だ/です/である」.（「～とは」≂「というのは」）. eg: ✕「空**と**は青い。」 → 〇「空**と**は青いものだ。」 〇「空は青い。」〇「空は青いものだ。」)</sub>

---

For your second sentence, it'd be natural to use には instead of とは, as in:

> ポム**には**、フランス語でりんご｛っていう/という｝意味がある。

*lit.* "In Pomme, there is the meaning 'apple' in French." → "Pomme means apple in French."
<sub>(This could imply Pomme can mean (an)other thing(s) too.)</sub>

(We often omit the に and say 「～～**は**～～っていう意味がある」 in casual speech.)

---

For the third, you can use the transitive suru-verb 「意味**する**」("to mean~~") if you want to use する:

> ポム**は**、フランス語でりんご**を意味する**。

"Pomme means apple in French."

This one sounds quite formal. To sound more casual you can say:

> ポムは、フランス語でりんごのことだ。

Answer (score 2):

> ポムとは、フランス語でりんごっていう意味だ。

Pomme means 'apple' in French. a = b

> ポムとは、フランス語でりんごっていう意味がある。

Pomme has the meaning of 'apple' in French (among other meanings). a = (b + α)

> ポムとは、フランス語でりんごっていう意味がする。✖

⇒ポムとは、フランス語でりんごっていう意味をする。（？）
Pomme takes on the meaning of 'apple' in french. Pomme denotes (represents) apple in French. a = b  ....... This would, however, likely be considered an unnatural-sounding sentence.

Comment: 「ポムとは、フランス語でりんごっていう意味をする。」  sounds strange and incorrect.

Comment: @Chocolate  While not necessarily in common usage, I thought it was the closest thing (grammatically) to that example. Ex: 「ヒャゥルプ」はアイスランド語で「助ける」という意味をする言葉で、重要な役割を担いました。That's the only example I could find, so I will put it down as 'unused'.

Comment: 「～～という意味をする言葉で・・」って、変ですね・・。「～～という意味を**持つ**言葉で、」のほうがいいですよね。